# Refresh main window's DataGrid after closing popup child window

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF `MainWindow.xaml`. The `MainWindow` includes a navigation page `Type.xaml`, and the navigation page has `DataGrid` and a popup Window `AddType.xaml`. `AddType` window adds data to database, and Type page shows the data in `Datagrid`.

I want the `MainWindow` (which has the Type page with `DataGrid`) to be refreshed after I close the popup Window.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Menu Name="menu1" >
            <MenuItem Header="Expenses" x:Name="typeExpense"
                      Click="typeExpense_Click"/>            
        </Menu>
       </StackPanel>
    <Frame Name="Main" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
           Margin="0,35,0,0">            
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void typeExpense_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Type type = new Type();
        Main.NavigationService.Navigate(type);            
    }
}
```

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Dobavit"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75" Margin="50,45,0,0" Click="btnAddWindow_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="10,100,10,10">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naimenovaniya"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=typename}"
                                Width="300"/>             
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class Type : Page
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"]
        .ConnectionString;
    public Type()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridBind();
    }
    protected void DataGridBind()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from type", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
    private void btnAddWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddType addtype = new AddType();
        addtype.Show();
    }
}
```

```
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Naimenovaniya"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="35,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="364" Margin="45,26,0,0"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnOK" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="85,77,0,0"
            Click="btnOK_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Otmena"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75" Margin="219,77,0,0" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class AddType : Window
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"]
        .ConnectionString;
    public AddType()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO type (typename) VALUES ('"+txtType.Text+"')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Close();
    }
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Youve posted statements and some code - wheres a question or problem?

Comment: I want the MainWindow (which has the Type page with dataGrid) to be refreshed after I close the popup Window.

Comment: I add data to DB using AddType popup window. Type page, which is navigated to mainWindow, describes that data in datagrid. Now when close the popup Window, Type window is not showing tha data whithout refreshing. The question is how can i solve that issue.

Comment: simplest answer is make the popup modal, so your main screen stops and then the code continues after the popup is complete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inserting a new record into the type table, you need to query the database again. You can do this by handling the `Close` event for the window:

```
private void btnAddWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddType  addtype = new AddType ();
    addtype.Closed += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        DataGridBind();
    };
    addtype.Show();
}
```